# How to change the order of the payment methods in Commerce?

Tags: commerce

How can I change the order of the payments methods in the last step before placing an order in Drupal Commerce?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the weight of the Rules for payment methods will change the order on order review page.

Comment: Visit `admin/commerce/config/payment-methods` and edit weight of the rules