# Steps for Changing the Order of the Payment Methods on Checkout

Tags: 7, commerce

I have two payment methods: Cheque and PayFlow Pro enabled for my products. However, they are showing up on the checkout form in an undesirable order:

Pay by Cheque (selected by default)
Pay by Credit Card

I'd like to reverse those and make Credit Card the default option. This question [APPEARS to be answered here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86603/how-to-change-the-order-of-the-payment-methods-in-commerce), but I don't understand the answer.

Would someone kindly provide the steps needed to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the payment method and click on **SETTINGS** on the bottom of the page.

[image]